# any "docker" command that i try to run on terminal throw this message "context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I was reading the Docker documentation about deploy Docker containers on AWS ECS https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/ . And after i run the command `docker context create ecs myecscontext` and select the option `AWS environment variables` every docker commands that i try to run throw this message on my terminal `context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables`. I've tried to set the AWS environments with the windows `set` command but it dosen't work.

I've used like this:

```
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=any-value
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=any-value
```

I'm searching how to solve this problem and the only thing that i've found is to set environment variables like i've already done. What i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I've find another way to set environment variables on windows in this site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-using-powershell

Instead use `set` i had to use `$env:VARIABLE_NAME = 'any-value'` this sintax to really update the vars.

Like this:

```
$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my-aws-access-key-id'
$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my-aws-secret-access-key'
```